# How can I use Equals or hashcode in my following program

Tags: c#

I want to fetch the details of manager from manager class if at run time I give kinid of employee from the employee class. How can I do this using Equals or Hashcode?

```
public class employee
{
    public string empname { get; set;}
    public string location { get; set; }
    public int kinid { get; set; }
    public double magkin { get; set; }
}

public class manager
{
    public string magname { get; set; }
    public double magkin { get; set; }
}

Dictionary<employee, manager> relation = new Dictionary<employee, manager>();
```

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used C# in a long time, but Something like this should work:
kinidFind is the kinid you want to search for.

```
manager findManager(int kinidFind) {
    foreach( KeyValuePair<employee, manager> i in relation) {
                    if (i.Key.kinid==kinidFind) {
                        return i.Value;
                    }
                }
}
```

Comment: simplified the return statement for you.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that kinid is a unique identifier (you don't care about other fields of employee in identifying), then on employee class you could do the following:

```
override int GetHashCode()
{
    return kinid;
}

override bool Equals(Object obj)
{
    if (obj == null) return false;
    emploee emp = obj as employee;
    if ((System.Object)emp == null) return false;

    return (kinid == emp.kinid);
}
```

However, this is not a good general solution because what if later on you want to find the employee by other fields?

Consider changing that dictionary to: 
Dictionary<int,manager> where the int is the kinid of the employee then it's self explanatory.

Answer (score 0):

or since the Dictionary has been loaded you can Enumerate it this way as well it's just a question of feel or taste at this point from Brads answer

```
foreach (var pair in relation)
{
    if (pair.key == kinidFind )
    {
       return relation[pair.key];
    }
}
```